# interactive brokers API execute details, how I get the entry price of a Future that i got?

Tags: python, interactive, trading, interactive-brokers

I would like to get the price of a future that I actually bought. I am getting crazy trying to make it work. I would like to know too how to get PnL in real time. When I am trying to do that It takes almost 5 minutes to change the value. Here is some code I am using from over here, it does works but I am not able to get the execution details.

import time

def read_positions():  # read all accounts positions and return DataFrame with information

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.common import TickerId
import pandas as pd
import time

class ib_class(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.all_positions = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['Account', 'Symbol', 'Quantity', 'Average Cost', 'Sec Type'])

    def error(self, reqId: TickerId, errorCode: int, errorString: str):
        if reqId > -1:
            print("Error. Id: ", reqId, " Code: ", errorCode, " Msg: ", errorString)

    def position(self, account, contract, pos, avgCost):
        index = str(account) + str(contract.symbol)
        self.all_positions.loc[index] = account, contract.symbol, pos, avgCost, contract.secType

    def positionEnd(self):
        self.disconnect()

ib_api = ib_class()
ib_api.connect("127.0.0.1", 7496, 10)
ib_api.reqPositions()
current_positions = ib_api.all_positions
ib_api.run()

return current_positions
```

def read_navs():  # read all accounts NAVs

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.common import TickerId
import pandas as pd
import time

class ib_class(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.all_accounts = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['reqId', 'Account', 'Tag', 'Value', 'Currency'])

    def error(self, reqId: TickerId, errorCode: int, errorString: str):
        if reqId > -1:
            print("Error. Id: ", reqId, " Code: ", errorCode, " Msg: ", errorString)

    def accountSummary(self, reqId, account, tag, value, currency):
        #if tag == 'NetLiquidationByCurrency':
            index = str(account)
            self.all_accounts.loc[index] = reqId, account, tag, value, currency


    def accountSummaryEnd(self, reqId: int):
        self.disconnect()

    def execDetails(self, reqId, contract, execution):
        print('Order Executed: ', reqId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, contract.currency, execution.execId,
              execution.orderId, execution.shares, execution.lastLiquidity)

ib_api = ib_class()
ib_api.connect("127.0.0.1", 7496, 10)
ib_api.reqAccountSummary(9001, "All", "$LEDGER")
current_nav = ib_api.all_accounts
ib_api.run()

return current_nav
```

while True:
time.sleep(0.1);
print(read_positions())

Comment: maybe you want https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/executions_commissions.html   Note you get avgCost in the position report if you need it.

Comment: Hey Brian, thanks. The point is that I dont know hot to put that in my code and get executions details. For me is really confusing this api. Can you help me with that?

Comment: What is real time PnL? Do you mean tick by tick, if so you have to subscribe to real time data to get current quotes.  accountSummary will update every few minutes on it's own.

Answer (score 1):

I remembered the was a new function [reqPnLSingle](http://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/pnl.html) so I wrote this to test.

There is some weird data but the value seems right and it updates continuously.

I put comments in code to explain.

```
import ibapi
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.common import *
from ibapi.contract import *

import pandas as pd
import collections 
import time

class TestApp(EClient, EWrapper):
    accts = []
    orderId = 0
    posns = collections.defaultdict(list)
    start = time.time()
    
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        
    def error(self, reqId:TickerId, errorCode:int, errorString:str):
        if (reqId > -1):
            # ignore many 2150 Invalid position trade derived value
            if (errorCode == 2150): return
            print("Error:", reqId, errorCode, errorString)
        else :
            print("Info: ", errorCode, errorString)
        
    def managedAccounts(self, accountsList: str):
        # the accounts are sent when a connection is made
        # only needed to reqPosns for sub acct
        self.accts = accountsList.split(",")# probably just 1
        print("accts", self.accts)
        
    def nextValidId(self, orderId:int):
        # this is called when a connection is made
        self.orderId = orderId
        
        # to make sure the version is >= min 9.73.06, server > ~127?
        print(ibapi.VERSION, self.serverVersion())

        #use this as a signal to start making requests
        self.reqPositions()
    
    def position(self, account: str, contract: Contract, position: float, avgCost: float):
        self.posns["account"].append(account)
        self.posns["conId"].append(contract.conId)
        self.posns["symbol"].append(contract.localSymbol)
        self.posns["avgCost"].append(avgCost)
        self.posns["posn"].append(position)
        
    def positionEnd(self):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(self.posns) #will make an automatic int index
        
        if (self.df.empty):
            self.disconnect()
            return
        
        # make req for each posn, use index for reqId
        for index, row in self.df.iterrows():
            self.reqPnLSingle(index, row.account, "", row.conId)
    
    def pnlSingle(self, reqId: int, pos: int, dailyPnL: float, unrealizedPnL: float, realizedPnL: float, value: float):
        row = self.df.iloc[reqId]
        # all PnL's are maxint for me at night so I calc the right amount
        print(row.symbol, "PnL", unrealizedPnL, "calc", value - row.avgCost * row.posn)
        
        #just run for ~10 secs
        if (time.time() - self.start > 10): 
            print(self.df)
            self.disconnect()
    
def main():
    app = TestApp()
    app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, 123)
    app.run()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Nice example! Would you know how to look up the fill price of a future contract bought at a specific time? For example, I buy a total of 3 contracts of the same symbol with each purchased at a different time. How can I look up the fill price of contract #2? reqPositions() only lists the ave price for all 3 contracts.

Comment: Either request or save the execution details of every order, they are sent after every fill.  https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/executions_commissions.html